# Why is our logo PLD instead of PLDI?

Tags: bug, site-logo

The sites full name is Programming Language Design and Implementation (the "and Implementation" part was added later but still there) and therefore one would expect it to be abbreviated to PLDI, not PLD. And yet it is abbreviated to PLD. Why?

Comment: I think it's just PLDI but cut off. The D seems to be nearly running off the right edge already

Comment: Well can that be fixed... @mousetail

Comment: Not really for beta sites, they don't have any custom code

Comment: Then what took a month to make this site if it literally copy pasting code!? See this:https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32939/congratulations-to-programming-language-design-and-implementation-on-completing-t @mousetail

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We do not have room for four characters. We limit the default logos to only 2 or 3 characters. We used to do single character ones but we stopped as it can be confusing. Honestly, PLD is big as it is and adding the I would make it illegible.

Answer (score 1):

Just presume the D stands for Development, as in the [top voted answer](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/42/26) on [What's the right domain name for this site?](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33/26) (disclaimer: I posted that question).

It's not unique: [Substrate and Polkadot](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/) still has a favicon (and a domain name) not mentioning the Polkadot part, even after [a site name change](https://substrate.meta.stackexchange.com/q/96/2).