# Can we get a site logo in the style of GenAI please

Tags: feature-request, site-logo

The new GenAI site seems to have gotten a logo that wraps over 2 lines:

[image]

A few places show [image: abc].

Most beta sites don't get custom logos. Since you seem to be willing to make exceptions, we would also like logo actually showed our full acronym without clipping past the right edge.

Either variant would be an improvement over our current logo.

- [Related](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251/can-we-get-a-custom-logo-in-the-top-left-like-stack-overflow-has)
- [Related](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/214/8)

A terrible rendition of what it could look like:

[image]

Comment: I know you are just asking to improve on the current but surely we can do better than just 4 letters? A random search gives [loads of inspiration](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=AB5stBghYoPSlUUfajmlaYFt6DmDz87glg:1689678922990&q=programming+languages&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjh1fS_kJiAAxVVxgIHHXlZDCoQ0pQJegQIDBAB&biw=1920&bih=899&dpr=1#imgrc=1ZS3bDaeqYz86M)

Comment: @BruceAdams I'd love an entirely custom logo but I'd settle for the one extra letter

Comment: @BruceAdams We won't get a non-blue-thought-bubble until we get a site design, which will be a while after we graduate. That could easily be half a decade from now, unfortunately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we get a custom logo in the top left like Stack Overflow has?](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251/can-we-get-a-custom-logo-in-the-top-left-like-stack-overflow-has)

Comment: @kaya3-supportthestrike I already references that question in the post